# How to add special character like "'" in JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, json, web-services, ios4

Is there any way to send some special character like **'**, **"** in **JSON** string, If I try to send this character in JSON, then I am **not** able to **get success response**.

Here is the code :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dicWebServiceData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dicWebServiceData setValue:@"Today's menu" forKey:@"description"];
NSString *strBulkData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bulk_data=[%@]",[dicWebService JSONRepresentation]];
strBulkData = [strBulkData stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


NSData *postData = [strBulkData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",webServiceURL,strWebServiceName]];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setTimeoutInterval:6000];
[req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Is there any way to pass this character in JSON ?
Thanks,

Comment: From the official page http://json.org -> A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, **using backslash escapes**. (emphasis mine)

Comment: Yes, json.org will tell you which characters need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You can't wrap a string literal over multiple lines without escaping the carriage returns.
You should use \ to make it multi line string. Hope it helps.

e.g.

```
NSString *size = [Content stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"return     Subject.min(\
document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,\
document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,\
document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight\
);"];
```